# Get path of file located in NuGet package's directory from same package in C#

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-assembly, filepath

I have a `.NET Framework (4.7)` solution which is referencing a NuGet package. This NuGet package should read from an `html` and an `xml` file. These files are both located within the packages' folder (NuGet package) and they are NOT needed by the solution directly, but only by the NuGet package itself.

How can I refer to these files when running the solution that is consuming the mentioned NuGet package?

I tried with `./` but all this does is point to the root directory of my solution instead.

The actual call that I am trying is: `File.ReadAllText(path)`.

I also tried to set `Copy to Output Directory` property of the files to `Copy always` and use `Build Action` as `Content`. This is copying these files in the `packages/<package name>/Content/*.html` for example and somehow I guess I can get this path, such as the solution given here: [Getting the path of a nuget package programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616239/getting-the-path-of-a-nuget-package-programmatically)

But this looks complicated to me for such a seemingly simple task. What is the clean way of doing this?

**Edit: Renamed question to specify that setting a resource is not an option in this case as some of the functions I'm consuming in the NuGet package are requesting a file path and not a resource.**

Comment: Is this a console app or web app? .NET Core? .NET Framework?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it's a .NET Framework solution.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a nuget package created by you, under any circumstances at runtime a external file should't be used! someone can alter it, if is needed add it as [embedded resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file).

Anyway, at runtime I would get the folder where the .dll stays like this:

```
 var currentAssemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
 var rootFolder = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Split(currentAssemblyName)[0];
```

**Edit** - should work for both .NET Framework or dotnet core

My mistake, to get the real path for the DLL you need to search for the Assembly, because ***ExecutingAssembly*** is from where the .exe was launched

```
 var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                          .GetAssemblies()
                          .SingleOrDefault(assembly => assembly.GetName().Name == "my.awsome.nuget");
 var location = assembly.Location;
```

Comment: you can also put a helper function in the package's assembly, then use `Assembly.GetCurrentAssembly()`. But by this point there's pretty much zero benefit compared to using an embedded resource.

Comment: Also a possibly easier way to get the directory with the assembly, rather than using split, is to use `Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location)`

Comment: `GetExecutingAssembly`, `GetCurrentAssembly` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies` all returned the solution's Debug folder path for me. Getting a resource is not an option for me as I have functions that take a path as an argument and not a resource.

Comment: yes, there is where the nugget stays, if you publish your application, nugget .dll is under the publish folder, so what is the problem?